# Mongoose methods on nested Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attaching some methods to a childSchema, nesting it in a parentSchema, and then modelling the parentSchema.  The childSchema seems to be undefined when this happens.  This seems to be what the Mongoose docs are telling me to do, but it isn't working.  Can anyone explain?

```
var childSchema = new Schema({name: 'string' });
childSchema.methods.getname = function () {
    return this.name;
};
var Child = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);


var parentSchema = new Schema({
  child: childSchema
});
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);

const parent = new Parent();
parent.child.getName();  // This does not work.  Can't getName of undefined

//Instead I have to do:
const parent = new Parent();
parent.child = new Child();
parent.child.getName();  // This works.
```

This seems terribly clunky for models with complex nested schemas.  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You are creating a `new Parent()` without passing any arguments to the constuctor which basically means that `parent` will be an empty document . How do you expect mongoose to create a `child` inside it and how this child will look like?

Comment: If you look at the parentSchema, it contains a childSchema.  This is how schemas are modeled inside the Mongoose documentation.